# MATLAB 'continue' command alternative

Tags: matlab, for-loop, continue

```
for i = 1:30
    if condition1
        statement1
    elseif condition2
        continue
    else
        statement2
    end
    statement3
end
```

As above, I have 'continue' command in a for loop to skip 'statement3' if condition2 is satisfied. This code works well.
But when I have to run the if-else part for test purpose, it makes an error because 'continue' should be run within a for/while loop.

Is there a way to do the same thing (do nothing and skip to the next iteration) in a for loop but also works separately?

Comment: You can simply comment the line of `continue` when testing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run the exact same code outside a loop, hence without being able to use `continue`, you can simply rewrite it as follows:

```
if ~condition2
    if condition1
        statement1
    else
        statement2  
    end

    statement3
end
```

Alternatively (I know it's not very elegant, but it does work indeed):

```
if condition1
    statement1
    statement3
elseif condition2
else
    statement2  
    statement3
end
```

The above code be improved (a lot) by rewriting it as follows:

```
if condition1
    statement1
    statement3
elseif ~condition2
    statement2  
    statement3
end
```

Finally, if your `statement3` is particularly long and you don't want to repeat it twice, you can further improve the code above using a bypass flag:

```
go3 = false;

if condition1
    statement1
    go3 = true;
elseif ~condition2
    statement2  
    go3 = true;
end

if go3
    statement3
end
```

The problem is that abstract conditions don't allow me to use my imagination at full potential. Maybe if you specify the conditions you are using, even in a simplified way, I could try to come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, what you wrote works as you want. check this code for example:

```
for i = 1:7
    if i<=2
        disp([num2str(i) ' statement1'])
    elseif i>=4 &&  i<=6
        disp([num2str(i) ' only continue here'])
        continue
    else       
        disp([num2str(i) ' statement2'])
    end
    disp([num2str(i) ' statement3']);
end
disp('yeah')


>>
1 statement1
1 statement3
2 statement1
2 statement3
3 statement2
3 statement3
4 only continue here
5 only continue here
6 only continue here
7 statement2
7 statement3
yeah
```

Second, You can do this as well

```
for i=1:30
    if condition1
        statement1
        statement3
    elseif condition2
        continue
    else
        statement2  
        statement3
    end
end
```

Comment: That last code block has a dangling `end`. Did an `if` statement accidentally get left out?